# java.lang.classcastexception com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.wsjdbcconnection incompatible with oracle.jdbc.oracleConnection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, websphere

Facing java.lang.classcastexception com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.wsjdbcconnection incompatible with oracle.jdbc.oracleConnection in websphere 8.5. The application running properly in weblogic

I am getting this Exception when running my code on Websphere8.5 using JNDI.However this same code is running fine on Weblogic 8.1,Tomcat 5.5,JBoss 4.2.x.
The Code also runs fine via *JNDI* using *Data sources (WebSphere Application Server V4)*

And the code also works fine when I am Running the application via non JNDI.But the below mentioned Exception is coming when I am using the *DataSource configuration* in Websphere via JNDI.

Below is the StackTrace of the Exception coming

```
com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection incompatible with oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
*java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection incompatible with oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection*
        at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:149)
        at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:115)
        at com.syfact.mo.administrator.pctr.LoadAction.loadPostalcodes(LoadAction.java:182)
        at com.syfact.mo.administrator.pctr.LoadAction.doAction(LoadAction.java:490)
        at com.syfact.web.servlet.Syfact.processStandardCommand(Syfact.java:370)
        at com.syfact.web.servlet.Syfact.doPost(Syfact.java:291)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:966)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:907)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:145)
        at com.syfact.ConnectionFilter.doFilter(ConnectionFilter.java:40)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:696)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:641)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:475)
        at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:463)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3107)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:238)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:811)
        at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1425)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:92)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:394)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:102)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:152)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:213)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.fireCompletionActions(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:195)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:193)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:725)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:847)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1498)
```

i have been searching for solutions on this problem for nearly a week and found one:

Example:

```
connection = (Connection) WSJdbcUtil.getNativeConnection((WSJdbcConnection)dataSource.getConnection()); 
OracleCallableStatement ocstmt = (OracleCallableStatement) connection.prepareCall(sql); "*
```

I do not want to have WAS libraries in my project because my code is not to be deployed only on websphere but it should be deployable on Tomcat,JBoss,Weblogic .etc......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to access JDBC driver vendor-specific interfaces, you need to use the JDBC spec-defined unwrap API which exists for this purpose,

```
OracleConnection oraCon = connection.unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class);
```

Comment: @daddy_cool this answer should resolve the problem in your question.  You are right that `WSJdbcUtil` is a vendor-specific API and would lock you into WebSphere (it's a very old deprecated WAS API).  Instead @njr is suggesting using the JDBC-standard `Connection.unwrap(Class<?> interface)` method, which should be portable to any JDBC compliant environment.  If that doesn't answer your question, you'll have to be more clear on what problem you are trying to solve

Comment: @daddy_cool Use the unwrap method, it will work in weblogic also as it is JDBC compliant way of getting to native connection from the pool.

Comment: java.sql.Connection.unwrap(interfaceClass) is the JDBC specification defined solution for accessing JDBC vendor-specific interfaces such as you are trying to do.
WSJdbcUtil is not portable across application servers.
Direct casting is not portable across application servers.
The only portable solution is the JDBC specification defined one: unwrap.